# How to access K3b configuration/settings?

Tags: configuration, dvd, settings

I bought a Laptop which came with Ubuntu. I need to access the settings to try and make my Ubuntu detect my acme DVD-R because it wont.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A9 DVD`

Answer (score 1):

K3B Settings are accessed via Settings->Configure K3B as shown below:
K3B should detect your devices automatically however.

[image: K3B-devices]